# Custom Neural Network Implementation on MNIST using Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I tried to write a custom implementation of basic neural network with two hidden layers on MNIST dataset using [`*TensorFlow 2.0 beta*`](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta) but I'm not sure what went wrong here but my **training loss** and **accuracy** seems to stuck at **1.5** and around **85** respectively. But If I build the using **Keras** I was getting very low training loss and accuracy above **95%** with just **8-10** epochs.

I believe that maybe I'm not updating my weights or something? So do I need to assign my new weights which I compute in backprop function backs to their respective weights/bias variables?

I really appreciate if someone could help me out with this and these few more questions that I've mentioned below.

**Few more Questions**:

1) How to add a **Dropout** and **Batch Normalization** layer in this custom implementation? (**i.e** making it work for both train and test time)

2) How can I use **callbacks** in this code? i.e (making use of EarlyStopping and ModelCheckpoint callbacks)

3) Is there anything else in my code below that I can optimize further in this code like maybe making use of **tensorflow 2.x** @tf.function decorator etc.)

4) I would also require to extract the final weights that I obtain for plotting and checking their distributions. To investigate issues like gradient vanishing or exploding. (Eg: Maybe Tensorboard)

5) I also want help in writing this code in a more generalized way so I can easily implement other networks like **ConvNets** (i.e Conv, MaxPool, etc.) based on this code easily.

Here's my full code for easy reproducibility **:**

> Note: **I know I can use high-level API like Keras to build the model much easier but that is not my goal here. Please understand.**

```
import numpy as np
import os
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train', 'test'], 
                                                  batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

# reshaping
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(x_train.shape[0], 784))
x_test  = tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(x_test.shape[0], 784))

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
# rescaling
ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda x, y: (tf.cast(x, tf.float32)/255.0, y))

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, device=None):
        # layer sizes along with input and output
        self.input_size, self.output_size, self.device = 784, 10, device
        self.hidden1_size, self.hidden2_size = hidden1_size, hidden2_size
        self.lr_rate = 1e-03

        # weights initializationg
        self.glorot_init = tf.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=42)
        # weights b/w input to hidden1 --> 1
        self.w_h1 = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.input_size, self.hidden1_size)))
        # weights b/w hidden1 to hidden2 ---> 2
        self.w_h2 = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.hidden1_size, self.hidden2_size)))
        # weights b/w hidden2 to output ---> 3
        self.w_out = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.hidden2_size, self.output_size)))

        # bias initialization
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.hidden1_size,)))
        self.b2 = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.hidden2_size,)))
        self.b_out = tf.Variable(self.glorot_init((self.output_size,)))

        self.variables = [self.w_h1, self.b1, self.w_h2, self.b2, self.w_out, self.b_out]


    def feed_forward(self, x):
        if self.device is not None:
            with tf.device('gpu:0' if self.device=='gpu' else 'cpu'):
                # layer1
                self.layer1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, self.w_h1), self.b1))
                # layer2
                self.layer2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(self.layer1,
                                                             self.w_h2), self.b2))
                # output layer
                self.output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(self.layer2,
                                                             self.w_out), self.b_out))
        return self.output

    def loss_fn(self, y_pred, y_true):
        self.loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, 
                                                                  logits=y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(self.loss)

    def acc_fn(self, y_pred, y_true):
        y_pred = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), tf.int32)
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32)
        predictions = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_mean(predictions)

    def backward_prop(self, batch_xs, batch_ys):
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.lr_rate)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predicted = self.feed_forward(batch_xs)
            step_loss = self.loss_fn(predicted, batch_ys)
        grads = tape.gradient(step_loss, self.variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.variables))

n_shape = x_train.shape[0]
epochs = 20
batch_size = 128

ds_train = ds_train.repeat().shuffle(n_shape).batch(batch_size).prefetch(batch_size)

neural_net = Model(512, 256, 'gpu')

for epoch in range(epochs):
    no_steps = n_shape//batch_size
    avg_loss = 0.
    avg_acc = 0.
    for (batch_xs, batch_ys) in ds_train.take(no_steps):
        preds = neural_net.feed_forward(batch_xs)
        avg_loss += float(neural_net.loss_fn(preds, batch_ys)/no_steps) 
        avg_acc += float(neural_net.acc_fn(preds, batch_ys) /no_steps)
        neural_net.backward_prop(batch_xs, batch_ys)
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Training Loss: {avg_loss}, Training ACC: {avg_acc}')

# output for 10 epochs:
Epoch: 0, Training Loss: 1.7005115111824125, Training ACC: 0.7603832868262543
Epoch: 1, Training Loss: 1.6052448933478445, Training ACC: 0.8524806404020637
Epoch: 2, Training Loss: 1.5905528008006513, Training ACC: 0.8664196092868224
Epoch: 3, Training Loss: 1.584107405738905, Training ACC: 0.8727630912326276
Epoch: 4, Training Loss: 1.5792385798413306, Training ACC: 0.8773203844903037
Epoch: 5, Training Loss: 1.5759121985174716, Training ACC: 0.8804754322627559
Epoch: 6, Training Loss: 1.5739163148682564, Training ACC: 0.8826455712551251
Epoch: 7, Training Loss: 1.5722616605926305, Training ACC: 0.8840812018606812
Epoch: 8, Training Loss: 1.569699136307463, Training ACC: 0.8867688354803249
Epoch: 9, Training Loss: 1.5679460542742163, Training ACC: 0.8885049475356936
```

Comment: By editing the question to add the part about avoiding the high level API after originally asking for ways to "improve the code" and changing from "basic implementation" to "custom implementation" and the countless other changes you have fundamentally changed the nature of the question.

Comment: When I run your code on my machine, I get an accuracy >95% and a loss <0.5 in less than 10 epochs

Comment: @rvinas I've tried it multiple times accuracy keeps varying but my training loss is stuck at around **1.4 to 1.5**. I've even ran it for like 20 epochs. If you try with keras I was able to get around 98-99 accuracy and training loss below 0.1 with just few epochs (like 10 or so)

Comment: @Stewart_R If you are justifying for the answer you've given please don't worry at all I'll just award you the bounty if I don't get any good ones. Just for sake of clarity. **I've very very clearly mentioned I was getting around 95% accuracy with keras but still you just gave me a sample keras code on how to implement it.** Also I did ask "If there's something I could improve **in the code**" and I've given my code right below but yet you just gave an sample example keras code. I only changed the title once.

Comment: @Stewart_R Please do understand I've only added **Note** because I got similar keras answer right below. I thought they are not reading the part where I clearly mentioned I was getting around 95% using keras.

Comment: @user_6396 Thank you. It would be nice to have your Keras implementation so that we can compare

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wondered where to start with your multiquestion, and I decided to do so with a statement:

**Your code definitely should not look like that and is nowhere near current Tensorflow best practices**.

Sorry, but debugging it step by step is waste of everyone's time and would not benefit either of us.

Now, moving to the third point:

> 3. Is there anything else in my code below that I can optimize further
>    in this code like maybe making use of tensorflow 2.x @tf.function
>    decorator etc.)

Yes, you can use `tensorflow2.0` functionalities and it seems like you are running away from those (`tf.function` decorator is of no use here actually, leave it for the time being).

Following new guidelines would alleviate your problems with your 5th point as well, namely:

> 5. I also want help in writing this code in a more generalized way so
>    I can easily implement other networks like ConvNets (i.e Conv, MaxPool
>    etc.) based on this code easily.

as it's designed specifically for that. After a little introduction I will try to introduce you to those concepts in a few steps:

## 1. Divide your program into logical parts

Tensorflow did much harm when it comes to code readability; everything in `tf1.x` was usually crunched in one place, globals followed by function definition followed by another globals or maybe data loading, all in all mess. It's not really developers fault as the system's design encouraged those actions.

Now, in `tf2.0` programmer is encouraged to divide his work similarly to the structure one can see in `pytorch`, `chainer` and other more user-friendly frameworks.

### 1.1 Data loading

You were on good path with [Tensorflow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview) but you turned away for no apparent reason.

Here is your code with commentary what's going on:

```
# You already have tf.data.Dataset objects after load
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train', 'test'], 
                                                  batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

# But you are reshaping them in a strange manner...
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(x_train.shape[0], 784))
x_test  = tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(x_test.shape[0], 784))

# And building from slices...
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
# Unreadable rescaling (there are built-ins for that)
```

You can easily generalize this idea **for any dataset**, place this in separate module, say `datasets.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


class ImageDatasetCreator:
    @classmethod
    # More portable and readable than dividing by 255
    def _convert_image_dtype(cls, dataset):
        return dataset.map(
            lambda image, label: (
                tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32),
                label,
            )
        )

    def __init__(self, name: str, batch: int, cache: bool = True, split=None):
        # Load dataset, every dataset has default train, test split
        dataset = tfds.load(name, as_supervised=True, split=split)
        # Convert to float range
        try:
            self.train = ImageDatasetCreator._convert_image_dtype(dataset["train"])
            self.test = ImageDatasetCreator._convert_image_dtype(dataset["test"])
        except KeyError as exception:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Dataset {name} does not have train and test, write your own custom dataset handler."
            ) from exception

        if cache:
            self.train = self.train.cache()  # speed things up considerably
            self.test = self.test.cache()

        self.batch: int = batch

    def get_train(self):
        return self.train.shuffle().batch(self.batch).repeat()

    def get_test(self):
        return self.test.batch(self.batch).repeat()
```

So now you can load more than `mnist` using simple command:

```
from datasets import ImageDatasetCreator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataloader = ImageDatasetCreator("mnist", batch=64, cache = True)
    train, test = dataloader.get_train(), dataloader.get_test()
```

And you could use any name other than `mnist` you want to load datasets from now on.

**Please, stop making everything deep learning related one hand-off scripts, you are a programmer as well**.

### 1.2 Model creation

Since `tf2.0` there are two advised ways one can proceed depending on models complexity:

- `tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential` - this way was shown by [@Stewart_R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57088397/10886420), no need to reiterate his points. Used for the simplest models (you should use this one with your feedforward).
- Inheriting `tensorflow.keras.Model` and writing custom model. This one should be used when you have some kind of logic inside your module or it's more complicated (things like ResNets, multipath networks etc.). All in all more readable and customizable.

Your `Model` class tried to resemble something like that but it went south again; `backprop` definitely is not part of the model itself, neither is `loss` or `accuracy`, **separate them into another module or function, defo not a member!**

That said, let's code the network using the second approach (you should place this code in `model.py` for brevity). Before that, I will code `YourDense` feedforward layer from scratch by inheriting from `tf.keras.Layers` (this one might go into `layers.py` module):

```
import tensorflow as tf

class YourDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        # It's Python 3, you don't have to specify super parents explicitly
        super().__init__()
        self.units = units

    # Use build to create variables, as shape can be inferred from previous layers
    # If you were to create layers in __init__, one would have to provide input_shape
    # (same as it occurs in PyTorch for example)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # You could use different initializers here as well
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        # You could define bias in __init__ as well as it's not input dependent
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal")
        # Oh, trainable=True is default

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Use overloaded operators instead of tf.add, better readability
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel) + self.bias
```

Regarding your

> 1. How to add a Dropout and Batch Normalization layer in this custom
>    implementation? (i.e making it work for both train and test time)

I suppose you would like to create a custom implementation of those layers.
If not, you can just import `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout` and use it anywhere you want as [@Leevo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123319/10886420) pointed out.
Inverted dropout with different behaviour during `train` and `test` below:

```
class CustomDropout(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, rate, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rate = rate

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training:
            # You could simply create binary mask and multiply here
            return tf.nn.dropout(inputs, rate=self.rate)
        # You would need to multiply by dropout rate if you were to do that
        return inputs
```

Layers taken [from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) and modified to better fit showcasing purpose.

Now you can create your model finally (simple double feedforward):

```
import tensorflow as tf

from layers import YourDense


class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Use Sequential here for readability
        self.network = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [YourDense(100), tf.keras.layers.ReLU(), YourDense(10)]
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        # You can use non-parametric layers inside call as well
        flattened = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
        return self.network(flattened)
```

Ofc, you should use built-ins as much as possible in general implementations.

**This structure is pretty extensible, so generalization to convolutional nets, resnets, senets, whatever should be done via this module**. You can read more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models).

I think it fulfills your 5th point:

> 5. I also want help in writing this code in a more generalized way so
>    I can easily implement other networks like ConvNets (i.e Conv, MaxPool
>    etc.) based on this code easily.

Last thing, you may have to use `model.build(shape)` in order to build your model's graph.

```
model.build((None, 28, 28, 1))
```

This would be for MNIST's `28x28x1` input shape, where `None` stands for batch.

### 1.3 Training

Once again, training could be done in two separate ways:

- **standard Keras `model.fit(dataset)`** - useful in simple tasks like classification
- **`tf.GradientTape`** - more complicated training schemes, most prominent example would be [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network), where two models optimize orthogonal goals playing minmax game

As pointed out by [@Leevo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123319/10886420) once again, if you are to use the second way, you won't be able to simply use callbacks provided by Keras, hence I'd advise to stick with the first option whenever possible.

In theory you could call callback's functions manually like `on_batch_begin()` and others where needed, but it would be cumbersome and I'm not sure how would this work.

When it comes to the first option, you can use `tf.data.Dataset` objects directly with fit. Here is it presented inside another module (preferably `train.py`):

```
def train(
    model: tf.keras.Model,
    path: str,
    train: tf.data.Dataset,
    epochs: int,
    steps_per_epoch: int,
    validation: tf.data.Dataset,
    steps_per_validation: int,
    stopping_epochs: int,
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
):
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        # I used logits as output from the last layer, hence this
        loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )

    model.fit(
        train,
        epochs=epochs,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        validation_data=validation,
        validation_steps=steps_per_validation,
        callbacks=[
            # Tensorboard logging
            tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
                pathlib.Path("logs")
                / pathlib.Path(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")),
                histogram_freq=1,
            ),
            # Early stopping with best weights preserving
            tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
                monitor="val_sparse_categorical_accuracy",
                patience=stopping_epochs,
                restore_best_weights=True,
            ),
        ],
    )
    model.save(path)
```

More complicated approach is very similar (almost copy and paste) to `PyTorch` training loops, so if you are familiar with those, they should not pose much of a problem.

You can find examples throughout `tf2.0` docs, e.g. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2).

## 2. Other things

### 2.1 Unanswered questions

> 4. Is there anything else in the code that I can optimize further in
>    this code? i.e (making use of tensorflow 2.x @tf.function decorator
>    etc.)

Above already transforms the Model into graphs, hence I don't think you would benefit from calling it in this case. And premature optimization is the root of all evil, remember to measure your code before doing this.

You would gain much more with proper caching of data (as described at the beginning of #1.1) and good pipeline rather than those.

> 5. Also I need a way to extract all my final weights for all layers
>    after training so I can plot them and check their distributions. To
>    check issues like gradient vanishing or exploding.

As pointed out by [@Leevo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123319/10886420) above,

```
weights = model.get_weights()
```

Would get you the weights. You may transform them into `np.array` and plot using `seaborn`, `matplotlib`, analyze, check or whatever else you want.

### 2.2 Putting it altogether

All in all, your `main.py` (or entrypoint or something similar) would consist of this (more or less):

```
from dataset import ImageDatasetCreator
from model import Model
from train import train

# You could use argparse for things like batch, epochs etc.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataloader = ImageDatasetCreator("mnist", batch=64, cache=True)
    train, test = dataloader.get_train(), dataloader.get_test()
    model = Model()
    model.build((None, 28, 28, 1))
    train(
        model, train, path epochs, test, len(train) // batch, len(test) // batch, ...
    )  # provide necessary arguments appropriately
    # Do whatever you want with those
    weights = model.get_weights()
```

Oh, remember that above functions are not for copy pasting and should be treated more like a guideline. Hit me up if you have any questions.

## 3. Questions from comments

### 3.1 How to initialize custom and built-in layers

#### 3.1.1 TLDR what you are about to read

- Custom Poisson initalization function, but it takes **three**
  arguments
- `tf.keras.initalization` API needs **two** arguments (see last point [in their docs](https://keras.io/initializers/)), hence one is
  specified via Python's `lambda` inside custom layer we have written before
- Optional bias for the layer is added, which can be turned off with
  boolean

Why is it so uselessly complicated? **To show that in `tf2.0` you can finally use Python's functionality**, no more graph hassle, `if` instead of `tf.cond` etc.

#### 3.1.2 From TLDR to implementation

Keras initializers can be found [here](https://keras.io/initializers/) and Tensorflow's flavor [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers).

Please note API inconsistencies (capital letters like classes, small letters with underscore like functions), especially in `tf2.0`, but that's beside the point.

You can use them by passing a string (as it's done in `YourDense` above) or during object creation.

To allow for custom initialization in your custom layers, you can simply add additional argument to the constructor (`tf.keras.Model` class is still Python class and it's `__init__` should be used same as Python's).

Before that, I will show you how to create custom initialization:

```
# Poisson custom initialization because why not.
def my_dumb_init(shape, lam, dtype=None):
    return tf.squeeze(tf.random.poisson(shape, lam, dtype=dtype))
```

Notice, it's signature takes three arguments, while it should take `(shape, dtype)` only. Still, one can "fix" this easily while creating his own layer, like the one below (extended `YourLinear`):

```
import typing

import tensorflow as tf


class YourDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    # It's still Python, use it as Python, that's the point of tf.2.0
    @classmethod
    def register_initialization(cls, initializer):
        # Set defaults if init not provided by user
        if initializer is None:
            # let's make the signature proper for init in tf.keras
            return lambda shape, dtype: my_dumb_init(shape, 1, dtype)
        return initializer

    def __init__(
        self,
        units: int,
        bias: bool = True,
        # can be string or callable, some typing info added as well...
        kernel_initializer: typing.Union[str, typing.Callable] = None,
        bias_initializer: typing.Union[str, typing.Callable] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.units: int = units
        self.kernel_initializer = YourDense.register_initialization(kernel_initializer)
        if bias:
            self.bias_initializer = YourDense.register_initialization(bias_initializer)
        else:
            self.bias_initializer = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Simply pass your init here
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
            trainable=True,
        )
        if self.bias_initializer is not None:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(
                shape=(self.units,), initializer=self.bias_initializer
            )
        else:
            self.bias = None

    def call(self, inputs):
        weights = tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
        if self.bias is not None:
            return weights + self.bias
```

I have added `my_dumb_initialization` as the default (if user does not provide one) and made the bias optional with `bias` argument. Note you can use `if` freely as long as it's not data dependent. If it is (or is dependent on `tf.Tensor` somehow), one has to use `@tf.function` decorator which changes Python's flow to it's `tensorflow` counterpart (e.g. `if` to `tf.cond`).

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph) for more on autograph, it's very easy to follow.

If you want to incorporate above initializer changes into your model, you have to create appropriate object and that's it.

```
... # Previous of code Model here
self.network = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        YourDense(100, bias=False, kernel_initializer="lecun_uniform"),
        tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
        YourDense(10, bias_initializer=tf.initializers.Ones()),
    ]
)
... # and the same afterwards
```

With built-in `tf.keras.layers.Dense` layers, one can do the same (arguments names differ, but idea holds).

### 3.2 Automatic Differentiation using `tf.GradientTape`

#### 3.2.1 Intro

Point of `tf.GradientTape` is to allow users normal Python control flow and gradient calculation of variables with respect to another variable.

Example taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/automatic_differentiation) but broken into separate pieces:

```
def f(x, y):
  output = 1.0
  for i in range(y):
    if i > 1 and i < 5:
      output = tf.multiply(output, x)
  return output
```

Regular python function with `for` and `if` flow control statements

```
def grad(x, y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(x)
    out = f(x, y)
  return t.gradient(out, x)
```

Using gradient tape you can record all operations on `Tensors` (and their intermediate states as well) and "play" it backwards (perform automatic backward differentiation using chaing rule).

Every `Tensor` within `tf.GradientTape()` context manager is recorded automatically. If some Tensor is out of scope, use `watch()` method as one can see above.

Finally, gradient of `output` with respect to `x` (input is returned).

#### 3.2.2 Connection with deep learning

What was described above is `backpropagation` algorithm. Gradients w.r.t (with respect to) outputs are calculated for each node in the network (or rather for every layer). Those gradients are then used by various optimizers to make corrections and so it repeats.

Let's continue and assume you have your `tf.keras.Model`, optimizer instance, `tf.data.Dataset` and loss function already set up.

One can define a `Trainer` class which will perform training for us. **Please read comments in the code if in doubt**:

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, model, optimizer, loss_function):
        self.model = model
        self.loss_function = loss_function
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        # You could pass custom metrics in constructor
        # and adjust train_step and test_step accordingly
        self.train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")
        self.test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")

    def train_step(self, x, y):
        # Setup tape
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Get current predictions of network
            y_pred = self.model(x)
            # Calculate loss generated by predictions
            loss = self.loss_function(y, y_pred)
        # Get gradients of loss w.r.t. EVERY trainable variable (iterable returned)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        # Change trainable variable values according to gradient by applying optimizer policy
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
        # Record loss of current step
        self.train_loss(loss)

    def train(self, dataset):
        # For N epochs iterate over dataset and perform train steps each time
        for x, y in dataset:
            self.train_step(x, y)

    def test_step(self, x, y):
        # Record test loss separately
        self.test_loss(self.loss_function(y, self.model(x)))

    def test(self, dataset):
        # Iterate over whole dataset
        for x, y in dataset:
            self.test_step(x, y)

    def __str__(self):
        # You need Python 3.7 with f-string support
        # Just return metrics
        return f"Loss: {self.train_loss.result()}, Test Loss: {self.test_loss.result()}"
```

Now, you could use this class in your code really simply like this:

```
EPOCHS = 5

# model, optimizer, loss defined beforehand
trainer = Trainer(model, optimizer, loss)
for _ in range(EPOCHS):
    trainer.train(train_dataset) # Same for training and test datasets
    trainer.test(test_dataset)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}: {trainer})")
```

Print would tell you training and test loss for each epoch. You can mix training and testing any way you want (e.g. 5 epochs for training and 1 testing), you could add different metrics etc.

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/advanced) if you want non-OOP oriented approach (IMO less readable, but to each it's own).

Comment: I've learned a few things from your answer. Thank you so much:) I've wanted to ask you something, here we've used keras model `(i.e model.fit)` right? But can you tell me how do I manually write the training process. i.e rather than using keras I'm trying to learn how to use gradient tape and manually calculate gradients and update it. It's okay even if I can't use callbacks.

Comment: Just one more doubt. Here in 1.2 section, how can I initialize weights differently for each layer. In some layer I might need something like `'glorot_normal'` instead of `'random_normal'`. An example with two dense layers would really help me a lot.

Comment: Edited my post, does this answer your questions? And sorry, might of went too basic, but might help others as well and better that way than the other I suppose.

Comment: Also in `tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)` , Does `self.model.trainable_variables` returns weights between dense layer to dropout layer if dropout was used? Do we have to differentiate w.r.t to dropout weights as well? I am assuming dropout is also a layer and it has some weights connecting to and from.

Comment: Yes. In **3.1** can you add a little bit detailed docs on what it does. I'm bit confused there.  Also in **1.1** **`tf.load`** requires you have to specify the split otherwise you'll get an error. Do check once. Other than that everything was good.

Comment: In **`tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)`**, does **`self.model.trainable_variables`** returns weights between dense layer to dropout layer also if dropout was used? Do we have to differentiate **w.r.t** to dropout weights as well? I am assuming dropout is also a layer and it has some weights connecting to and from.

Comment: No, dropout has no learnable weights. It's just a random binary mask over a `tensor`. Say output from `Dense` layer has the size `(batch, 50)`, then `Dropout` layer will create random `(batch, 50)` mask (with specified probability, usually `0.5`) and multiply it to zero out some layer outputs or activations. There is nothing to train here. We differentiate w.r.t. every node, but those which are zeroed out will not have any gradient, effectively updates will only pass through the non-zeroed out activations.

Comment: Above would be considered naive dropout. Usually, `inverse dropout` is implemented, where except zeroing out some part of outputs, those left untouched are multiplied by `1/probability` (hence their power is increased). In such case, during testing/inference, dropout layer does nothing and can be safely removed after training.

Comment: Added `3.1` TLDR which explains what's going on and rationale behind it, should be easier to follow now. Fixed dataset and added error catching if default `train`, `test` split is not present for the provided dataset (although those usually should be and `split` argument is not obligatory, see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load), if it's `None`, dict with `train` and `test` keys is usually returned).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196982/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-user-6396).

Comment: The Donald Knuth's quote is always on point :) "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: OOP is also (as well as 'premature optimization') mainly needed in libraries development, and is unnecessary all around -- splitting your Tasks doesn't need wrapping/incapsulating each of them in class -- everything needed is already wraped in TF. Anyway, thank you for such broad-minded answer

Answer (score 6):

> Also If there's something I could improve in the code do let me know
>   as well.

Embrace the high-level API for something like this. You can do it in just a few lines of code and it's much easier to debug, read and reason about:

```py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train', 'test'], 
                                                  batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

x_train = tf.cast(tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(x_train.shape[0], 784)), tf.float32)
x_test  = tf.cast(tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(x_test.shape[0], 784)), tf.float32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: @stewart-r thank you :) I just wanted to know how it works a little better so that's why I stayed away from using keras. These's high level api's are getting so easier that I often forget what actually happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to write a custom implementation of basic neural network with
>   two hidden layers on MNIST dataset using tensorflow 2.0 beta but I'm
>   not sure what went wrong here but my training loss and accuracy seems
>   to stuck at 1.5 and around85's respectively.

Where is the training part? Training of TF 2.0 models either Keras' syntax or **Eager execution** with `tf.GradientTape()`. Can you paste the code with conv and dense layers, and how you trained it?

---

Other questions:

> 1) How to add a Dropout layer in this custom implementation? i.e
>   (making it work for both train and test time)

You can add a Dropout() layer with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
```

And then you insert it into a Sequential() model just with:

```
Dropout(dprob)     # where dprob = dropout probability
```

---

> 2) How to add Batch Normalization in this code?

Same as before, with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

The choise of *where* to put batchnorm in the model, well, that's up to you. There is no rule of thumb, I suggest you to make experiments. With ML it's always a trial and error process.

---

> 3) How can I use callbacks in this code? i.e (making use of
>   EarlyStopping and ModelCheckpoint callbacks)

If you are training using Keras' syntax, you can simply use that. Please check this [very thorough tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/) on how to use it. It just takes few lines of code.
If you are running a model in **Eager execution**, you have to implement these techniques yourself, with your own code. It's more complex, but it also gives you more freedom in the implementation.

---

> 4) Is there anything else in the code that I can optimize further in
>   this code? i.e (making use of tensorflow 2.x @tf.function decorator
>   etc.)

It depends. If you are using Keras syntax, I don't think you need to add more to it. In case you are training the model in Eager execution, then I'd suggest you to use the `@tf.function` decorator on some function to speed up a bit.
You can see a practical TF 2.0 example on how to use the decorator in [this Notebook](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_02_MiniBatch_Gradient_Descent.ipynb).

Other than this, I suggest you to play with **regularization techniques** such as weights initializations, L1-L2 loss, etc.

---

> 5) Also I need a way to extract all my final weights for all layers
>   after training so I can plot them and check their distributions. To
>   check issues like gradient vanishing or exploding.

Once the model is trained, you can extract its weights with:

```
weights = model.get_weights()
```

or:

```
weights = model.trainable_weights
```

If you want to keep only trainable ones.

---

> 6) I also want help in writing this code in a more generalized way so
>   I can easily implement other networks like convolutional network (i.e
>   Conv, MaxPool etc.) based on this code easily.

You can pack all your code into a function, then . At the end of [this Notebook](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_01_basic_Classifier.ipynb) I did something like this (it's for a feed-forward NN, which is much more simple, but that's a start and you can change the code according to your needs).

### ---

**UPDATE**:

Please check my [TensorFlow 2.0 implementaion of a CNN classifier](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_05_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb). This might be a useful hint: it is trained on the **Fashion MNIST** dataset, which makes it very similar to your task.

Comment: I hoped this question could be read and useful for many people. If you are not interested in Keras, simply read the **Eager execution** code that I linked to you.