# How to properly use `@tf.function` while subclassing keras Layer/Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a custom `tf.keras.layers.Layer` which do some kind of bit unpacking (converting integers to booleans values (0 or 1 float)) using only TF operators.

```
class CharUnpack(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, name="CharUnpack", *args, **kwargs):
        super(CharUnpack, self).__init__(trainable=False, name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        # Range [7, 6, ..., 0] to bit-shift integers
        self._shifting_range = tf.reshape(
            tf.dtypes.cast(
                tf.range(7, -1, -1, name='shifter_range'),
                tf.uint8,
                name='shifter_cast'),
            (1, 1, 8),
            name='shifter_reshape')
        # Constant value 0b00000001 to use as bitwise and operator
        self._selection_bit = tf.constant(0x01, dtype=tf.uint8, name='and_selection_bit')

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.dtypes.cast(
            tf.reshape(
                tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(
                    tf.bitwise.right_shift(
                        tf.expand_dims(inputs, 2),
                        self._shifting_range,
                    ),
                    self._selection_bit,
                ),
                [x if x else -1 for x in self.compute_output_shape(inputs.shape)]
            ),
            tf.float32
        )

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        try:
            if len(input_shape) > 1:
                output_shape = tf.TensorShape(tuple(list(input_shape[:-1]) + [input_shape[-1] * 8]))
            else:
                output_shape = tf.TensorShape((input_shape[0] * 8,))
        except TypeError:
            output_shape = input_shape
        return output_shape

    def compute_output_signature(self, input_signature):
        return tf.TensorSpec(self.compute_output_shape(input_signature.shape), tf.float32)
```

I tried to benchmark this layer to improve the time performance as shown in this [TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#the_tffunction_decorator).

```
inputs = tf.zeros([64, 400], dtype=tf.uint8)

eager = CharUnpack()

@tf.function
def fun(x):
    eager(x)

# Warm-up
eager(inputs)
fun(inputs)

print("Function:", timeit.timeit(lambda: fun(inputs), number=100))
print("Eager:", timeit.timeit(lambda: eager(inputs), number=100))
```

```
Function: 0.01062483999885444
Eager: 0.12658399900101358
```

As you can see, I can get a 10 times speed-up!!!
So, I added the `@tf.function` decorator to my `CharUnpack.call` method:

```
+    @tf.function
     def call(self, inputs):
         return tf.dtypes.cast(
```

Now I expect both, the `eager` and the `fun`, calls to spend similar time, but I get no improvement.

```
Function: 0.009667591999459546
Eager: 0.10346330100037449
```

Moreover, in section 2.1 of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57136842/11543584) states that Models are graph-compiled by default (which should be logic), but this does not seem to be the case...

How to properly use the `@tf.function` decorator to make my layer always graph-compiled?

Comment: Hi! Have you solved your issue? Does tf function improve performance of custom layer??

Comment: @cappadavide I did not play with TF since then and did not investigate any further. For sure, using `tf.function` can improve the performance, but I don't know the canonical way to use it… Feel free to do some experiments with newer versions of TF and please, share your insights !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tldr*: `fun()` doesn't return anything, `tensorflow` autograph is smart enough to realize this and ignores all the TF computations happening within `fun()`, whereas `eager(x)` **has to** execute what's happening in the `call()` function. This is why you're getting a ridiculously low execution time for `fun()`. At least that's what I think is happening - I'm not an AutoGraph expert so others might be able to correct me if I've got anything wrong.

### Problem investivation

Before we dive in, let's simplify things a git. First I modified your original code as follows. Let's increase the size of the data to make sure there's enough number crunching involved and data transfers and other overheads are not dominating the profiling.

```
inputs = tf.zeros([8192, 400], dtype=tf.uint8)
```

Second, I stripped out some computations e.g. `compute_output_shape()` and pinned the shape. Also brought some tensor definitions inside `call()`. So that `call()` takes care of variable definitions to computations end-to-end.

```
class CharUnpack(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    
    def __init__(self, name="CharUnpack", *args, **kwargs):
        super(CharUnpack, self).__init__(trainable=False, name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self._shifting_range = None
        self._selection_bit = None

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):

        if not self._shifting_range:
          # Range [7, 6, ..., 0] to bit-shift integers
          self._shifting_range = tf.reshape(
            tf.dtypes.cast(
              tf.range(7, -1, -1, name='shifter_range'),
              tf.uint8,
              name='shifter_cast'
            ),
            (1, 1, 8),
            name='shifter_reshape')
        
        if not self._selection_bit:
          # Constant value 0b00000001 to use as bitwise and operator
          self._selection_bit = tf.constant(0x01, dtype=tf.uint8, name='and_selection_bit')

        return tf.dtypes.cast(
            tf.reshape(
                tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(
                    tf.bitwise.right_shift(
                        tf.expand_dims(inputs, 2),
                        self._shifting_range,
                    ),
                    self._selection_bit,
                ),
                [x if x else -1 for x in self.compute_output_shape(inputs.shape)]
            ),
            tf.float32
        )

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return [8192, 3200]
```

Thirdly, I've set `number=1` in the timeit operation to make sure we're profiling a single call at a time. This makes it easier to understand.

```
# The very first call of either approach
print("Eager:", timeit.timeit(lambda: eager(inputs), number=1))
print("Function:", timeit.timeit(lambda: fun(inputs), number=1))
# The second call
print("Eager:", timeit.timeit(lambda: eager(inputs), number=1))
print("Function:", timeit.timeit(lambda: fun(inputs), number=1))
```

First let's look at the concrete function of `eager()`

```
eager_concrete = eager.call.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 400], dtype=tf.uint8))

print(eager_concrete)
```

which gives,

```
ConcreteFunction call(inputs)
  Args:
    inputs: uint8 Tensor, shape=(None, 400)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=(8192, 3200)
```

Let's look at the concrete function of `fun()`

```
fun_concrete = fun.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 400], dtype=tf.uint8))

print(fun_concrete)
```

which gives,

```
ConcreteFunction fun(x)
  Args:
    x: uint8 Tensor, shape=(None, 400)
  Returns:
    NoneTensorSpec()
```

So you straight away see that `fun()` is not returning anything, which should raise red flags in your mind. Going a bit further, we can look at what actually entails the graph that resulted from AutoGraph's tracing.

```
graph = fun_concrete.graph
for node in graph.as_graph_def().node:
  print(f'{node.input} -> {node.name}')
```

which outputs,

```
[] -> x
['x'] -> CharUnpack/StatefulPartitionedCall
```

Next, if you do the same for `eager()`, you will see all the primitive TF operations listed as below.

```
[] -> inputs
[] -> StringFormat
['StringFormat'] -> PrintV2
[] -> shifter_range/start
...
['Reshape'] -> Cast
['Cast', '^NoOp'] -> Identity
```

We can even look at the generated code.

```
print(tf.autograph.to_code(fun.python_function))
```

which gives,

```
def tf__fun(x):
    with ag__.FunctionScope('fun', 'fscope', ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, user_requested=True, optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True)) as fscope:
        out = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(eager), (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
```

So looking at the code, all it does is generating a [converted call](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f9aa9e6b869c6f2f169a9c5c32932da4d0a4f490/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py#L295) for `eager` and `x`

I'm not an AutoGraph expert but I imagine that all it's doing is passing a given input `x` to `eager.call()` and skipping all of the computations. So `fun()` is just skipping all the important computations in `eager.call()` function.

### How do we make `fun()` actually do the computations?

Simply add a `return` statement to `fun()`.

```
@tf.function
def fun(x):
  out = eager(x)
  return out
```

which gives,

```
Eager: 0.6245606249999582
Function: 0.3163724480000383
Eager: 0.2076279070001874
Function: 0.22467646699988109
Eager: 0.25076841500003866
Function: 0.240701412999897
```

So now we can see that both `eager.call()` and `fun()` taking the same time.

From [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values) it says,

> With the exception of tf.Variables, a tf.function must return all its outputs.

Though the section is highlighting a different face of the problem, it's possibly (indirectly) related to what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailled answer. I don’t use TF a lot anymore and cannot investigate further to validate your solution. So, actually my use of @tf.function is useless as I don’t return anything, and so my whole experiment was meaningless ^^

Comment: It was definitely an interesting edge case we don't think often of. It had me stumped for a few days until I figured out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

First, `tf.function` does not need nested using, i.e., you can only wrap your custom `train_step()` (contain propagation). In this case, there is no need to wrap inner layer or sub model's `call()` function, since they are involved in your `train_step`. Nested useage may lead to some unexpected performance degradation.

Second, any computational acceleration comes at a cost, `tf.function` is a way of exchanging space for time and need initialization to build `Graph`. So, when benchmark, we should re-run  the same function for several times, since a secondary call of `tf.function` do not cost building time as long as `Tracing` changes nothing.

```
for _ in range(5):
    print("Function:", timeit.timeit(lambda: fun(inputs), number=100))
for _ in range(5):
    print("Eager:", timeit.timeit(lambda: eager(inputs), number=100))
# Function: 0.02040819999820087
# Function: 0.020311099986429326
# Function: 0.020155799997155555
# Function: 0.02004839999426622
# Function: 0.019999900003313087
# Eager: 0.035980800006655045
# Eager: 0.035652499995194376
# Eager: 0.035596200003055856
# Eager: 0.03490520000923425
# Eager: 0.03762050000659656
```